# Cookie not being saved in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session-cookies

This is driving me crazy. I cannot for the life of me set cookies when frontend and backend are on different URLs.

When logging in, this is the **RESPONSE HEADERS**, coming from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 118
ETag: W/"76-RnnHeJL+YLKFl67NESlMHiQ6x/0"
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3ACghwEkLQD5wf2RvMI_wlDJ2il84ICWCj.UfPMDPG5jqeCmmPTxOqO3FCyQPIHLxu5VL5XbvX0aco; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 18 Feb 2025 02:27:06 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 02:27:06 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

**Both frontend and backend are HTTPS**.

Cookie is set to: **HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None**

Cookie is simply **NOT BEING SAVED:**

[image]

Comment: I feel like this might be the cause ... https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/